# Difference between merge and join in mssql

Tags: sql-server, merge, inner-join

I want to update a table t1 with data from t2. I can do in two ways. Can you tell me the difference in terms of accuracy and performance.

1.

```
merge into t1 using t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.name <> t2.name
when matched then update set t1.name=t2.name
```

2.

```
 update t1 set t1.name=t2.name from t1, 
 inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
 where t1.name <> t2.name
```

Comment: Is there some reason why you cannot test this for yourself?

Comment: Only time for cliff notes, 1. can use the target in the output clause. 2. Multiple operations available so no if statements and simplified code. 3. Performance may vary as with everything depends on your implementation.